# How to pip install wily tool for python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, pip

Currently my project is using in old python version 2.7 and in order to keep track of source code complexity, git pre-commit hook, HTML Graph report of work I would like to use python pip tool [wily](https://pypi.org/project/wily/).

However, since pip wily support only python 3, I am looking for way I could install it for my current project implementing python 2.7. How could I install it for python 2.7?

One workaround solution I could think of is to set up a separate python 3 virtual environment for wily and check python 2.7 source code, it is possible? Thanks

Comment: No, you can also install pip for python2 here is the link https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/

Comment: @AdamStrauss, thanks, I already have pip installed. My problem is I unable to install wily tool on python version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU the project requires Python 3. At Oct 14, 2018 (a year ago now) the author [formally declared](https://github.com/tonybaloney/wily/commit/7c4a9239e29a1e32ddb424fc372b9b8f8c405bed#diff-522adf759addbd3b193c74ca85243f7dR8) that the project requires Python 3.6+.